# add numbers to the names in the column of text file, starting a new numbering for each name in BASH

Tags: bash, text, numbers, rename, enumerate

Good morning,

I have tab-delimited file, which have repeated names in the first column:

```
X 
X
Y
Y
Y...
```

(input)

I want to rename these names by assigning numbers to them. The numbering must start anew for each name:

```
X_CDS1
X_CDS2
Y_CDS1
Y_CDS2
Y_CDS3...
```

(output)

Can you tell me, please, how this can be implemented in bash?

Thank in advance,
Poecile

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do add 3 important things in your question. 1st: Sample of input, 2nd: Sample of output and 3rd: your tried code as your efforts. Please do edit your question with these details and let us know then, thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the community rules yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F '\t' '$1 != "" {$1 = $1"_CDS"++seen[$1]} 1' OFS='\t' file.tsv > new.tsv
```